# Bing Spell Check API works only in English

Tags: spell-checking, bing-api

Trying  [Bing Spell Check API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/spell-check/?v=18.05), but it doesn't seem to work correctly with languages other than English. [Available languages for Spell Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/bing-spell-check-supported-languages)

I've tried to check French text, but the results will actually suggest mistakes to a perfectly fine text and vice versa (meaning it also won't correct a mistake in a text).

I've tried checking this text:

> La Terre a un noyau interne solide

This is how I've passed the language:

```
var result = client.SpellCheckerWithHttpMessagesAsync(text: text, mode: "spell", acceptLanguage: "fr-FR").Result;
```

I've also tried setLang:

```
var result = client.SpellCheckerWithHttpMessagesAsync(text: text, mode: "spell", setLang: "fr-FR").Result;
```

The result suggested changing **solide** to **solid** which is wrong.
I've tried other texts as well as different languages with the same results.

Am I missing something in how to use this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls use market parameter **mkt=fr-fr** in the query and drop the setLang parameter.

Comment: I don't see this option in the C# SDK.
I've tried a REST requestion, but id doesn't seem to work as well:
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/spellcheck?mode=spell&mkt=fr-fr&text=riviere

Comment: curl -X GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/spellcheck?text=La%20Terre%20a%20un%20noyau%20intern&mkt=fr-fr&mode=spell" works for me and corrects the incorrect spelling.

Comment: That's also working for me. Seems I can't get the C# SDK to work though.
Thank you for your help!